# confusing/surprising (??) thing about connections on vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $E\rightarrow M$ be a vector bundle.

A connection on $E\rightarrow M$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear map $\nabla:\Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\nabla(-,s):\Gamma(M,TM)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ is a morphism of $C^\infty(M)$-modules for each $s\in \Gamma(M,E)$,
2. $\nabla(X,-):\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ is a not really a morphism of $C^\infty(M)$-modules, but, its failure is "controlled" in the sense, $$\nabla(X,fs)=f\nabla(X,s)+{\color{red}{X(f)s}},$$
   for all $X\in \Gamma(M,TM)$ and $s\in \Gamma(M,E)$

Now, curvature associated to $\nabla$ is a map $$R_\nabla:\Gamma(M,TM)\times\Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E),$$
defined as
$$R_\nabla(\alpha, \beta,s)=\nabla([\alpha,\beta],s)-\nabla(\alpha,\nabla(\beta,s))+\nabla(\beta,\nabla(\alpha,s))$$
for $(\alpha,\beta,s)\in \Gamma(M,TM)\times\Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,E)$. Unlike the map $\nabla$, the associated map $R_\nabla$ is $C^\infty(M)$-multilinear. In particular, for each $(X,Y)\in \Gamma(M,TM)\times \Gamma(M,TM)$ the map $R_\nabla(X,Y,-):\Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$ is $C^\infty(M)$-linear, thus, should be coming from an endomorphism of $E$. So, we actually have $R_\nabla(X,Y,-)\in \Gamma(M,{\rm End}(E))$.

The $\mathbb{R}$-multilinearity of $R_\nabla$ says we have $R_\nabla:\Gamma(M,TM)^{\otimes 2}\rightarrow \Gamma(M,{\rm End}(E))$. Skew symmetric property says, we have $R_\nabla:\Lambda^2 \Gamma(M,TM)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,{\rm End}(E))$. In other words, we have a differential $2$-form on $M$ with values in the vector bundle ${\rm End}(E)\rightarrow M$. This is not the case with $\nabla$. There is no $1$-form in any sense that one can associate with $\nabla$.

This is not the case in case of principal bundles. We always are in the set up of differential forms; connection $1$-form and curvature $2$-form. Without going to principal bundle set up, is there a convincing answer to the following question?

Question : Is it not weird that we are starting with something that is in no sense related to "being a differential form" and end up with a differential form?

I remember writing some justification for this situation, but could not find it now and I don't remember what I wrote.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: I understand there may be any "answer" for this.. In any case, hoping for some related/useful comments.

Comment: The connection is not a tensor, whereas curvature is. You have a $\mathfrak g$-valued $1$-form on the principal bundle, yes, but not globally on the manifold. In the vector bundle case, the moving frames set-up certainly makes it clear that we end up with forms.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sir, I am trying to think this from a point of view of student who learns connection for the first time.. they may not have any idea about frame bundle or principal bundle.. So, with out going to that set up of principal bundles, can we give a reasonable justification for the question "something that is not a tensor is becoming a tensor"?

Comment: If you mimic the scalar case, you can say that by starting with a connection on the vector bundle, you get a whole bunch of operators, the exterior covariant derivative $d_{\nabla}$ which takes $E$-valued $k$-forms on $M$ to $E$-valued $(k+1)$-forms on $M$. This is analogous to how starting with $d$ acting on functions, we can extend to define exterior derivative of all (scalar) differential forms. In the scalar case, it turns out $d^2=0$, but in the $E$-valued case, this is no longer true necessarily. This essentially gives you a definition of the curvature as an endomorphism valued 2-form.

Comment: And that particular formula for the curvature drops out immediately from the definition of the exterior covariant derivative.

Comment: I think the motivation comes by working out the case of connection and curvature with moving frames on a surface.

Answer (score 3):

I think your initial point of view is a bit confusing. There is a clear motivation for what a linear connection on a vector bundle should be: It should provide a notion of "directional derivative" for sections of the bundle $E$. Since there is no global notion of "direction" on a manifold, you have to allow the direction into which you differentiate to depend on the point in which you differentiate. It is natural to assume that this dependence is smooth, so you are led to looking at a vector field $X$ on $M$ and then given a section $s$ of $E$, you would like to form in each point $x\in M$ the derivative of $s$ at $x$ in direction $X(x)$. From this description it is clear that, concerning the dependence on $X$, the value of such a "derivative" in $x$ should only depend on $X(x)$ (and not on derivatives of $X$ in $x$). Equivalently, if you view such a derivative as an operation $\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$ it should be linear over smooth functions in the first entry. However, in order to be a reasonable "derivative" the operation cannot be allowed to be linear over smooth functions in the second variable. Otherwise its value in $x$ would only depend on the value of the section in $s$, which should not be true for a derivative.

In that sense, the defining properties of a linear connection are completely natural, and it is clear that this cannot be a differential form. I agree that it is surprising that you can obtain a tensorial quantity (which has a point-wise meaning) from this via the definition of the curvature. But this is by forming clever combinations which make the terms that obstruct linearity over smooth functions cancel and in a way this is what the theory of connections is about. So the point I want to make is that it is surprising that you get a differential form from a connection, but it is not that the defining properties of a connection are strange.

Concerning the picture of principal connections: Here the counterpart of what you observe in the picture of linear connections is that the curvature form of a principal connection is horizontal (and hence descends to the base) while the connection form is as non-horizontal as possible. (By definition the connection form is injective on the vertical subbundle which the cuvature form vanishes upon insertion of one horizontal vector field.) THe difference to the linear case comes from the fact that the connection form is not actually used to differentiate something but rather to select the vector in the direction of which we should differentiate. Again, it is surprising that using principal bundles the theory of connections can be phrased in such a nice form, and of course you can get hints toward that by computing in moving frames.